# Node sass Error while doing npm install

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, node-sass

i was trying to do an npm install command, But ended up with an error related node sass.

I learning react/redux from the "https://github.com/buckyroberts/React-Redux-Boilerplate" from this. and doing npm install fails.

The error is attached as image.[image]
 I am using windows 7, with node 6.9. any idea to solve this error?

Answer (score 2):

Step-1: open command prompt with administrator priviledges.

Step-2: type in the following command:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

This will install all the dependencies required.

Step-4: Now run the following command:

```
npm install node-sass
```

And you are good to go !

If you still face problems. Please refer to this page:
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a package that depends on native build tools. Do you have Visual Studio installed? If not, try installing it first and reboot before retrying npm install.

Your issue may be related to https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1379

Answer (score 0):

the version 8.0.0 is the good for node js 18

node-v18.18.0  ====>  "node-sass": "^8.0.0",

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).