# npm install throwing error in node-sass installation

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, gulp-sass, node-sass

I am trying to do an npm install command, But getting below error while installing the `node-sass`.

[image]

[image]

**package.json :**

```
{
  "name": "XXXXX",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.4.9",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.3.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "angular-ui-bootstrap": "2.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-open": "2.0.0",
    "gulp-run": "^1.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp-jsbeautifier": "^2.0.3",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.10"  
  },
  "author": "XXXXX",
  "license": "XXX"
}
```

My Node version is `v6.9.2` and NPM version is `3.10.9`.

I tried below SO links to find some solution but did not work.

- [npm install throwing error in node-sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45589179/npm-install-throwing-error-in-node-sass)
- [node-sass installation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45876943/node-sass-installation-issue)
- [Node sass Error while doing npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41077826/node-sass-error-while-doing-npm-install)

Answer (score 2):

You are possibly behind of proxy server. You should do proxy settings to access github for downloading node-sass.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this problem before and the reason was for more than one node binaries, but in Windows I don't know if it should be possible.

Anyway, if this is the problem, there is a way to force npm to run package scripts with the same binary as npm uses when it executes, using:

```
npm config set scripts-prepend-node-path true
```

If you don't want it, and you want that npm uses the same binary of node when you executes directly $ node.... you can do:

```
npm config set scripts-prepend-node-path false
```

If the problem is due to different binaries anyone works.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

If you are in China somehow you should install with VPN

```
sudo npm install node-sass --save-dev
```